# What is the minimally required server to deploy JSF 2.0 project?

Tags: deployment, jsf-2

I can either install Tomcat or glassfish server in the production server inorder to deploy my JSF 2.0 project. Which from which versions of these servers are compatible with JSF 2.0? Please give suggestion.

I have developed with Mojarra 2.0.2, Facelets and PrimeFaces, Netbeans 6.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you need at least a server that supports Servlet 2.5 or later for JSF 2.0 (found at [coreservlets.com JSF 2.0 tutorial](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/#Getting-Started)), e.g.:

- Tomcat 6+
- Glassfish 2.1+
- Jetty 6+
- Google App Engine
- JBoss 5+
- WebSphere 6+
- WebLogic 9+

If not integrated, you then need `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` for JSF 2.0

If you have a server that supports Java EE 6 (Glassfish 3, JBoss 6, WebLogic 11g) these jar's are already included.

Answer (score 1):

JSF 2.0 uses version 2.5 of the servlet-api, which means it should be compatible with Tomcat version 6.0.x.

Sources:

http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.0.0/releasenotes.html
http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html